# Why is the checkSelfPermission method missing?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-permissions

My client requested to test their APK.
I installed that app my Android 6 and Android 4.
But it crashed when it started.

**Error**

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission
```

**Implementation**

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ...
}
```

What's the cause of this crash? The version of the android-support-v4.jar?
My client said android-support-v4.jar is included in the build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of the Android support library used is not updated. You should update the jar file with the latest one.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will announce to my client.